# Avro, Kafka message keys inserting extraneous characters

Tags: python, apache-kafka, avro, ksqldb

I have my topic built like this

```
producer = AvroProducer(
            config.confluent.connection_config(config.confluent.CONNECTION_MODE_PRODUCER),
            default_value_schema=get_avro_schema_object(),
            default_key_schema=avro.loads('{"type": "string"}'))

producer.produce(topic=topic, value=d, key=str(d['identifier']))
```

that all seems fine, but when i publish, i get keys like this

```
print 'build_pipe_dev';
Format:AVRO
12/9/19, 12:04:23 PM EST, +$something-unique-1, {"identifier": "something-unique-1", "event_type": "build_queued", "build_request": null, "build_queued": {"jobid": "job.torque.yup"}, "build_started": null, "build_finished": null, "static_analyze_request": null}
```

See, in my message key field, instead of it being `something-unique-1`, its `+$something-unique-1`.  I scratched my head all morning about this and i realized that its avro inserting its mojo into the field for the serializer/deserializer.  problem is, when i don't include a key schema, the `confluent_kafka` library throws an error because of this in the produce function

```
if key is not None:
            if key_schema:
                key = self._serializer.encode_record_with_schema(topic, key_schema, key, True)
            else:
                raise KeySerializerError("Avro schema required for key")
```

I have seen in other posts where people monkey patched the `confluent_kafka` library, but is there the "proper" way to solve this?

i suppose, theres another thing to consider, is it simply working properly and I'm overreacting?

Answer (score 1):

KSQL only supports STRING keys currently. It won't deserialise your Avro properly, hence the strange characters you're seeing in the key field.

If you use kafkacat, for example, you'll be able to consume your message and view the Avro key correctly.

Comment: so, does that mean things are working correctly?  as long as the schema never changes (which it shouldn't) im thinking im fine.

Comment: Depends if you're relying on the keys in your KSQL processing. If you are you'd need to use string keys, either at source (which as you've said isn't possible from the Python client since it's either/or at the moment IIRC) or by rekeying the data in KSQL (`CREATE STREAM foo AS SELECT * FROM source PARTITION BY new_key`)